# Count and compute: from files; I;m kinda lost on how to get going (Noobie here)

Tags: c, count, strstr

Im going an assignment on trying to count the number of certain keywords in a source code. I for the life of me just don't know how to do it.

For example, my code is suppose to do this

> ```
>   number of total lines
>
>     number and percentage of blank lines
>
>     number and percentage of comments (start with // or /*)
>
>     number and percentages of ints, longs, floats, doubles, char
>
>     number and percentages of if's
>
>     number and percentage of else's
>
>     number and percentage of for's
>
>     number and percentage of switch
>
>     number and percentage of semicolons
>
>     number and percentage of structs
>
>     number and percentage of arrays (contains [ or ], divide count by 2)
>
>     number of blocks (contains { or }, divide count by 2)
> ```

This is the little I done so far

```
int main()
{

FILE * bsfile;

bsfile = fopen("bship.txt", "r");
char singleLine[150];

while (!feof(bsfile))  {
    fgets(singleLine, 150, bsfile);
    puts(singleLine);


}

   fclose(bsfile);


    return 0;
}
```

It pretty much writes the whole file into the console, than shuts off. If anyone can help me by explaining to me how to find for examples the number of ifs, it would really help me a lot and get me started. I tried google and such, no luck on how I can get this to work. I know I'm suppose to use a counter with the for()?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is reading one line from file and putting it in string. Now fgets() is used in loop with a same string which will keep overwriting previous lines. This is not the safe way of copying file data into string. This is unnoticed by you because you are printing everyline after getting it into string. If you had used puts after the while loop you will realize the problem.

You should use double pointer to character and dynamically allocate 2D array for every lines and keep getting lines by using fgets for every 1D array or use single pointer and copy whole data into single string which is dynamically allocated using fgetc()

After getting data into string, use strstr() with your search strings to count repeatitions of particular keywords and your work is done. Only thing you have to do then is compute percentage for every keyword which is not a tough job.

Comment: The way I did it, is it consider bad coding? (Im a noob here, so i'm trying to learn as much as possible, i'm 3 weeks into learning c with no prior computer language exp). I ttried learning strstr, but I didn't know how to make it work for this scenario.

Comment: I also want to say thank you for taking the time to write to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{

FILE *bk;

bk = fopen("brick.c", "r");
char singleLine[1000];
int a=  0;

int totalLines = 0;
int numberofifs = 0;
int blankLine = 0;
int comLines = 0;
int intLines = 0;
int longLines = 0;
int floatLines = 0;
int doubleLines = 0;
int charLines = 0;
int ifLines = 0;
int elseLines = 0;
int forLines = 0;
int switchLines = 0;
int semiLines = 0;
int structLines = 0;
int arrayLines = 0;
int blockLines = 0;

float percentofbl;
float percentofcl;
float percentofint;
float percentoflong;
float percentoffloat;
float percentofdouble;
float percentofchar;
float percentofif;
float percentofelse;
float percentoffor;
float percentofswitch;
float percentofsemi;
float percentofstruct;
float percentofarray;
float percentofblock;





while (!feof(bk))  {
    fgets(singleLine, 1000, bk);
    totalLines++;

    for( a =0; singleLine[a] != '\0'; a++){ // Loops to scan the whole source code//
            // scanning blank lines //
            if (a == 0 && singleLine[a] == '\n' && singleLine[a+1] == '\0')
                blankLine++;
            // scanning comment lines //
            if ( singleLine[a] == '/' && ( singleLine[a+1] == '/' ||  singleLine[a+1] == '*'))
                comLines++;
            // scanning int line //
            if ((singleLine[a] == ' ' || singleLine[a] == '\t') && singleLine[a+1] == 'i' && singleLine[a+2] == 'n' && singleLine[a+3] == 't')
                intLines++;
            // scanning longs line //
            if ((singleLine[a] == ' ' || singleLine[a] == '\t') && singleLine[a+1] == 'l' && singleLine[a+2] == 'o' && singleLine[a+3] == 'n'
                && singleLine[a+4] == 'g')
                longLines++;
            // scanning floats line //
            if ((singleLine[a] == ' ' || singleLine[a] == '\t') && singleLine[a+1] == 'f' && singleLine[a+2] == 'l' && singleLine[a+3] == 'o'
                && singleLine[a+4] == 'a' && singleLine[a+5] == 't')
                floatLines++;
            // scanning doubles line //
          if ((singleLine[a] == ' ' || singleLine[a] == '\t') && singleLine[a+1] == 'd' && singleLine[a+2] == 'o' && singleLine[a+3] == 'u'
          && singleLine[a+4] == 'b' && singleLine[a+5] == 'l' && singleLine[a+5] == 'e')
          doubleLines++;
            // scanning chars line //
                if ((singleLine[a] == ' ' || singleLine[a] == '\t') && singleLine[a+1] == 'c' && singleLine[a+2] == 'h' && singleLine[a+3] == 'a'
                && singleLine[a+4] == 'r')
                charLines++;
            // scanning if's line //
                if ((singleLine[a] == ' ' || singleLine[a] == '\t') && singleLine[a+1] == 'i' && singleLine[a+2] == 'f')
                ifLines++;
            // scanning else's line //
                if ((singleLine[a] == ' ' || singleLine[a] == '\t') && singleLine[a+1] == 'e' && singleLine[a+2] == 'l' && singleLine[a+3] == 's'
                && singleLine[a+4] == 'e')
                elseLines++;
            // scanning for line //
                if ((singleLine[a] == ' ' || singleLine[a] == '\t') && singleLine[a+1] == 'f' && singleLine[a+2] == 'o' && singleLine[a+3] == 'r')
                forLines++;
            // scanning switch line //
                if ((singleLine[a] == ' ' || singleLine[a] == '\t') && singleLine[a+1] == 's' && singleLine[a+2] == 'w' && singleLine[a+3] == 'i'
                && singleLine[a+4] == 't' && singleLine[a+5] == 'c' && singleLine[a+5] == 'h')
                switchLines++;
            // scanning semicolons line //
                if (singleLine[a] == ';')
                semiLines++;
            // scanning structs line //
                if ((singleLine[a] == ' ' || singleLine[a] == '\t') && singleLine[a+1] == 's' && singleLine[a+2] == 't' && singleLine[a+3] == 'r'
                && singleLine[a+4] == 'u' && singleLine[a+5] == 'c' && singleLine[a+5] == 't')
                structLines++;
            // scanning arrays [ line //
                 if (singleLine[a] == '[')
                 arrayLines++;
            // scanning blocks { line //
                 if (singleLine[a] == '{')
                 blockLines++;




    percentofbl =  (float)blankLine/totalLines * 100;
    percentofcl = (float)comLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentofint = (float)intLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentoflong = (float)longLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentoffloat = (float)floatLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentofdouble = (float)doubleLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentofchar = (float)charLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentofif = (float)ifLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentofelse = (float)elseLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentoffor = (float)forLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentofswitch = (float)switchLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentofsemi = (float)semiLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentofstruct = (float)structLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentofarray = (float)arrayLines/totalLines * 100;
    percentofblock = (float)blockLines/totalLines * 100;

    }




}
printf("The total number of lines is %i\n",totalLines);
printf("The total number of blank lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n",blankLine, percentofbl );
printf("The total number of comment lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", comLines, percentofcl);
printf("The total number of int lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", intLines, percentofint);
printf("The total number of long lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", longLines, percentoflong);
printf("The total number of float lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", floatLines, percentoffloat);
printf("The total number of double lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", doubleLines, percentofdouble);
printf("The total number of char lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", charLines, percentofchar);
printf("The total number of if lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", ifLines, percentofif);
printf("The total number of else lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", elseLines, percentofelse);
printf("The total number of for lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", forLines, percentoffor);
printf("The total number of switch lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", switchLines, percentofswitch);
printf("The total number of semicolon lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", semiLines, percentofsemi);
printf("The total number of structs lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", structLines, percentofstruct);
printf("The total number of arrays lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", arrayLines, percentofarray);
printf("The total number of blocks lines is %i and percentage is %lf \n", blockLines, percentofblock);


fclose(bk);


    return 0;
}
```